# Can you configure a different logfile for pip2 and pip3, yes/no? if yes, how?

Tags: python, pip, configuration

I still have legacy python code to support. But I am also doing some python3 development.

I have pip configured with config file:

```
[global]
log = /home/USER_NAME/.local/pip/pip.log
format = columns
```

The problem is that pip2 and pip3 both use the same log file.

#### Can you configure a different logfile for pip2 and pip3, yes/no? if yes, how?

p.s. if there were an option to specify the config file i could just have an alias for pip2, pip3 where the alias has the different config files but alas I did not see any pip option for specifying the config file.

p.p.s. all my pip install commands are "--user" (i am against sudo pip install usually/generally).

---

Here's a workaround:

Create a new script pip2 and pip3 and put it on your path ahead of pip2 and pip3. **These scripts will at least show what parts of the log file are generated by pip2 and pip3.**

pip2 script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')]: pip2" $@ >> ~/.local/pip/pip.log
python2 -m pip $@
```

pip3 script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')]: pip3" $@ >> ~/.local/pip/pip.log
python3 -m pip $@
```

Comment: How about using virtual environments (which is the best practice anyway). Then each virtual env has its own config file https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file In that case just make sure to **not** have a global config file since it will have precedence

Comment: @DeepSpace different virtualenv for python2 and python3 each with it's own pip.conf might be the way to go. because it does what the question asks (i.e. a different logfile for pip2 and pip3). it just requires a little extra work.

Comment: About the workaround that you added. If you are already redirecting the output in both scripts then why not simply redirect to separate files? `>> ~/.local/pip/pip2.log` and `>> ~/.local/pip/pip3.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you use pip2 and pip3 outside of virtualenv --> then no (see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053096/can-you-configure-a-different-logfile-for-pip2-and-pip3-yes-no-if-yes-how#comment116784435_66053096))
- if you are in a virtualenv then you can have a different conf file which has a different log file configure for each virtual env --> then yes (for each virtualenv you can have separate pip conf file that specifies a different log file)